# Have my Room database in place, but it keeps crashing. Am I using it wrong? (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room

I have set up my `Room` database properly (I think) and build it in my `AsyncTask` to keep it from blocking the main thread. But when I use the `insert` from `Dao`, it crashes with the error `RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()` and `SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.id`. It crashes on the line where I try to inser data in the `database` `myDatabase.getUserDao().insert( user1, user2 );`

Here is my `AsyncTask`

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<Context> contextRef;
    public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.contextRef = new WeakReference<Context>( context );
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... notused) {
        Log.d("TAG ", "BACKGROUND STUFF");

        Context context = contextRef.get();

        MyDatabase myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            MyDatabase.class,
            "myDatabase.db")
            .build();

        UserEntity user1 = new UserEntity();
        user1.setId( 22 );
        user1.setName( "TESTING1" );

        UserEntity user2 = new UserEntity();
        user2.setId( 3 );
        user2.setName( "TESTING2" );

        myDatabase.getUserDao().insert( user1, user2 );

    return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {}

}
```

The `Database`

```
@Database( entities = {UserEntity.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract UserDao getUserDao();

}
```

The `Dao` `interface`:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(UserEntity... users);

    @Query( "SELECT * FROM users" )
    List<UserEntity>getAllUsers();

    @Update
    void update(UserEntity... users);

    @Delete
    void delete(UserEntity... userEntities);   
}
```

And the `Entity` class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class UserEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? And one more thing I can't seem to solve. Once I have successfully put data into Room, how do I use the interface `getAllUsers()`?

***UPDATE*** Forgot `onCreate()` though there isn't much to show.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
    myAsyncTask.execute(  );
}
```

Comment: `autoGenerate` should be false if you are planning to handle ids on your own

Comment: @tore Maybe you have executed MyAsyncTask twice.

Comment: As @Blackbelt said, you cant use user1.setId( 22 ); if you have the id to be autogenerated=true. Eighter set it to false or dont set the ID of the USer.

Comment: Didn't work with `autogenerate` set to false. How do I know `asynctask` isn't executed twice?